How to inherit and modify SidebarFilter Javascript widget which was declared locally and not been return in the file Odoo 14
I have a requirement to modify the filter of the Calendar view, which uses SidebarFilter. However, in calendar_renderder.js that widget is created and used in the extended AbstractRenderer, which is a return value. How can I achieve this?
calendar_renderder.js
odoo.define('web.CalendarRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";

var SidebarFilter = Widget.extend(FieldManagerMixin, {
    
    init: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        ..........
    }
.........
});

return AbstractRenderer.extend({
.....
});


have a look to the addon: hr_holiday that has a custom calendar renderer js/xml
